# Error parsing XML: junk after document element - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, android, xml, android-virtual-device

Error: Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element
    - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top|left">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have more than one root element: both `<menu>` and `<LinearLayout>` are loose in the document and not contained in some other elelement.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the empty menu tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
            android:gravity="top|left">
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

So you can't use it with Linearlayout.

Comment: first paragraph: totally irrelevant. Second paragraph: factually inaccurate. This isn't about the content of those tags, just that there are two of them and they aren't surrounded by an overall "root" element.